# Can this function with modulo and truncated division be simplifed?

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic

Can this function with modulo and truncated division (`DIV`) be simplifed?

```
f(x)=(x%c)*r+DIV(x,c)%r
```

Basically, I use this function to reoder the elements of a r*c matrix. Given this...

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
```

..applying the function on the indexes (linearly) gives me this:

```
 1  4  7 10
 2  5  8 11
 3  6  9 12
```

Comment: Seems pretty simple to me, given what you're trying to do.

Comment: I know. It's just that the symmetry of the operations made me think there might be a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

I think   `DIV(x,c)%r` should be simplified to `DIV(x,c)`. The result of division will not exceed $r$. It may be equal to $r$ if $x=rc$; however, I hold that this should not happen because $0$-based   numbering should be used.

With $r=3$ and $c=4$, the given formula produces $f(1)=3$, $f(2)=6$, $f(3)=9$... I don't this was intended. For the formula to rearrange the cell numbers as intended, they should be numbered starting with $0$:

```
 0  1  2  3  
 4  5  6  7  
 8  9 10 11
```

Now applying `(x%c)*r+DIV(x,c)` to each entry gives

```
 0  3  6  9 
 1  4  7 10
 2  5  8 11
```

which is the desired rearrangement.